# Call an intent's response card from another intent

Tags: lambda, amazon-lex

I see that this question explains how to call another intent : [How to call Intent B from intent A in AWS lex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147655/how-to-call-intent-b-from-intent-a-in-aws-lex)

However the confirmIntent responds with a text message that we pass to the function. How can I elicit a slot instead of the text message?

Im trying to call Intent B's response card to fill a slot value from Intent A. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your scenario with a Lex V2 bot that has a Python Lambda function configured.

In my bot, `IntentB` uses the Lambda function as its fullfilment code hook.

The function returns the following response which instructs Lex to elicit the required slot in `IntentA`.

```
{
   "sessionState":{
      "dialogAction":{
         "slotToElicit":"Number",
         "type":"ElicitSlot"
      },
      "intent":{
         "confirmationState":"None",
         "name":"IntentA",
         "state":"InProgress"
      }
   }
}
```

My response is built using the formats as described in the [Lex developer Guide - Lambda Response Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html#lambda-response-format).